# .Net Regex Replace - Multiline while searching for filepaths

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking to sanitize a string that contains file paths, to remove the parent path for more secure logging.

It needs to:

- be case insensitive.
- support unlimited capture replaces.
- work in .net
- accept that the paths being provided or replaced are automated (i'm creating the search pattern dynamically) and therefore any string fu that occurs needs to be replicated in an automated fashion

I am wanting to take a multiline string like:

```
The file was: C:\\outputpath\\testfile.htm
And the second file was: C:\\OutputPath\\subfolder\\testfile2.htm'
```

and have it find and replace to output:

```
The file was: testfile.htm
The second file was: subfolder\\testfile2.htm
```

I have been trying with this:

```
var pathToRemove = "c:\\outputPath";
var sourceRegex = new Regex(".*(" + pathToRemove + ").*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var sanity = sourceRegex.Replace(input, String.Empty, 1000);
```

I'm getting an exception

`Unrecognized escape sequence \o.`

Comment: Are you only interested in replacing the string `c:\\output`, or are you wanting to remove any reference to any local file path?

Comment: Just the mentioned file path.

Comment: If you add '@', like  @"c:\\outputPath", then exception will disappear.

Comment: It does. But I also end up with an empty output string :(

Comment: @Doug:do you want to get file names from paths?or you want to remove "c:\\outputPath" from path?

Comment: I just want to remove them. don't really care what the matches are, just want a multiline regex replace to santize the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string pathToRemove = @"c:\\outputpath\\";
Regex sourceRegex = new Regex(pathToRemove, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string sanity = sourceRegex.Replace(input, string.Empty);
```

Comment: It's always the simple things that get me too.